# iOS Facebook API don't bring up the iPhone settings like Tweeter

Tags: facebook, ios6

I'm using [DEFacebookComposeViewController](https://github.com/sakrist/FacebookSample) for post a message in Facebook. When using iOS5 the user is redirected to the facebook page for login and then go back to the app, that works nice. But, in iOS6 the Service API show a UIAlertView that show the options "Settings" or "Cancel"

[image]

The problem is that bot buttons have the same effect. Both cancel the dialog (it's also happend in the 'FacebookSample' [here](https://github.com/sakrist/FacebookSample)).

In the other hand, the Tweeter framework woks fine in both iOS 5 and 6. The alerts appears if there is no tweeter account configured and the "Settings" button brings you to the "Add Account" screen.

All ideas are welcome.

Thanks

PD: all test where in the simulator.

*Edit:*

This is the code that I'm using:

```
DEFacebookComposeViewController *facebookComposer = [[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [facebookComposer setInitialText:@"Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test Test"];

            __block id weakSelf = self;
            [facebookComposer setCompletionHandler:^(DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResult result) {
                [weakSelf dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            }];

            [self presentModalViewController:facebookComposer animated:YES];
            [facebookComposer release];
```

And this is the important part in the `DEFacebookComposeViewController` class;

```
- (id)init
{
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6) {
        self = [(DEFacebookComposeViewController*)[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook] retain];
        return self;
    }

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self facebookComposeViewControllerInit];
    }
    return self;
}
```

There. If the iOS version is 6 the init method return `[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]` wich is the vanilla iOS6 way of interact with facebook.

Answer (score 1):

How about using Social framework that is officially provided by Apple on iOS6, especially on iOS6 ?

Ex:

```
SLComposeViewController  *viewController
  = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]; 

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```